# Indeterminacy locus of meromorphic maps of rigid analytic spaces

Tags: reference-request, complex-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry, berkovich-geometry, meromorphic-functions

**Setup.** Let $k$ be an algebraically closed field of characteristic zero. Let $X/k$ be a normal variety, and let $Y/k$ be a proper variety. It is well-known that the indeterminacy locus of a rational map $X \dashrightarrow Y$ has codimension at least $2$ (see Lemma 3.2 of [here](https://www.jmilne.org/math/xnotes/AVs.pdf) for a proof). The complex analytic variant of this statement where rational map is replaced by meromorphic map was proved by Remmert; see e.g., Theorem 2.5 of [here](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/BFb0070571) for the statement.

**Question.** Is there an analogous result for rigid analytic/Berkovich/adic spaces? More precisely, if I have a meromorphic map from a normal rigid analytic space to a proper rigid analytic space, does the indeterminacy locus have codimension at least $2$?

I am hopeful that such a result has been proved somewhere as there are a large quantity of articles proving non-Archimedean variants of results of Remmert and studying meromorphic maps; however I have not been able to find such a reference.

I would appreciate any references for this question or any examples providing a negative answer to the question.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Since this answer might be of use to other people in the future, I wanted to add an answer to this question. Brian Conrad provided me with a proof of this fact, which is written up Section 3 of [arXiv 2105.04352](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2105.04352.pdf).